# socat et al.: run a command when incoming connection is received

Tags: tcp, socat

Let's say one is listening on a tcp port for an incoming connection using socat like this:

```
$ socat file:`tty`,echo=1 "TCP-L:8080"
```

Is is possible to run a command (just once) when connection is received? It can be any command, though I intend to run `notify-send` to get a notification.

Answer (score 3):

Use `exec` or `system` to run commands, not `file`:

```bash
socat -U tcp-listen:8000,reuseaddr,fork exec:date
```

Here running the `date` command and sending its output to the client upon each connection, using an `U`nidirectional flow from the second to the first address (or IOW, the output of `date` is sent to the socket, but data coming from the socket is not sent to `date`).

Or to run `notify-send` and send a message back to the client, using `system` to get a shell:

```bash
socat -U tcp-listen:8000,reuseaddr,fork 'system:{
  if
    notify-send "Got connection from $SOCAT_PEERADDR:$SOCAT_PEERPORT"
  then
    # sending to the client
    echo OK: notification sent successfully
  else
    echo ERROR: could not send notification
  fi
}'
```

Note the `{...}` are interpreted as some kind of quotes by `socat` preventing it from treating characters such as `,` or `"` specially within, but as it happens are also passed along to `sh` where they're just treated as a command group.

The errors (of `sh`, `notify-send` or `echo` if any) are sent on `socat`'s stderr, not to the client, though that can be changed by passing the `stderr` option:

```bash
socat -U tcp-listen:8000,reuseaddr,fork 'system:{
  if
    notify-send "Got connection from $SOCAT_PEERADDR:$SOCAT_PEERPORT"
  then
    # sending to the client
    echo OK: notification sent successfully
  else
    echo ERROR: could not send notification
  fi
},stderr'
```

Comment: Works well, though the output of echo appears on the connecting side. Can one pipe the echo on the listening side? ``socat -U tcp-listen:8000,reuseaddr,fork 'system:/bin/echo helloworld >somefile.log,stderr'``?

Comment: Yes, that's the whole point. Stdout goes to the TCP client. If you wanted the stdout of the command/shell to go  to socat's stdout, you could add `,fdout=333` for instance to tell socat that's what's written on fd 333 instead that goes to the client (and fd 1 (stdout) is left alone).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with socat but with nc...

```
while true; do $CMD | nc -l 8080; done
```

(stdout will be returned to client).

OTOH you could use xinetd or systemd-socket-activate

Comment: This runs the command before receiving a connection since the shell sets up the pipeline first by running both `$CMD` and `nc` and only then waits for them to exit.